# Can't get Images to float left center and right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get images to display, one on the left, one in the center, and one on the right, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my HTML.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="modelListing"> 
        <a href="modelOne.html">
            <img src="modelOne.jpg" alt="Model One" class="modelThumb left" id="modelOneThumb" />
        </a><br /> 
        <span class="productThumbName"><a href="modelOne.html" class="noBold">Model Name</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="modelListing"> 
        <a href="modelTwo.html">
            <img src="modelTwo.jpg" alt="Model Two" class="modelThumb center" id="modelTwoThumb" />
        </a><br /> 
        <span class="productThumbName"><a href="modelTwo.html" class="noBold">Model Name</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="modelListing"> 
        <a href="modelThree.html">
            <img src="modelThree.jpg" alt="Model Three" class="modelThumb right" id="modelThreeThumb" />
        </a><br /> 
        <span class="productThumbName"><a href="modelThree.html" class="noBold">Model Name</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page uses this CSS script:

```
body{
    background-image:url('bg.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    font-family: Arial; 
    color:#B5B5B5;
    text-align:center;
}
.content{
    font-size:1.25em; 
    margin:10px 100px;
}
img.modelThumb{
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
.center{
    float:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

I'm probably making a simple mistake here but any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There is no `float: center` in css. always refer docs like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) before innovating your own properties :).

Comment: You need to rearrange your markup... Order it left, right, then your center.

Comment: .center { margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; } There is no center float.

Comment: float:center doesnt exist , maybe this can help you : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/fLcms

Comment: I would apply the class for positions on the divs not the anchor.

Comment: If you want your element to stay in the center in the right order you can use `display: inline-block` on `.modelListing` and `text-align: center` on `.content`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/ueY7c/

Answer (score 0):

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b9cs2/)

style

```
 .content{
    font-size:1.25em; 
    margin:10px 100px;

}
.modelListing{
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}
img.modelThumb{
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.right{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.center{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

add left, right, center class to DIVs

Comment: if you don't want images centered, just change text-align to left and right of the styles.